# Passing jQuery objects to functions

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble understanding how to pass a jQuery object between functions. I keep getting undefined values when trying to use val after passing jQuery objects to a function.

Very simple JS Fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/BtVqc/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function doSomething(objectOne, objectTwo) {
        $('table').append('<tr><td>' + objectOne.val() + '</td><td>' + objectTwo.val() + '</td></tr>');
    }

    $('button').click(function () {
        var tdOne = $('td.yy');
        var tdTwo = $('td.xx');
        doSomething(tdOne, tdTwo);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The correct selector for the input is `td .xx` not `td.xx`

```
var tdOne = $('td .yy');
var tdTwo = $('td .xx');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BtVqc/2/

`td.xx` means - a table cell that has `xx` class

`td .xx` means - some node that has `xx` class and is nested to a table cell